# Associating Microsoft word/excel with sqlite

Tags: excel, sqlite, ms-word

I would like to ask if anyone knows if there is any possible way to associate Microsoft word or  excel with sqlite ? 
For example, the Microsoft word document is store inside the database.

**Inside the Microsoft word document**

> Dear[Name],
>
> We are pleased to announce you that you have completed [Course].
>
> Thanks

In this Microsoft word document, can the fields [Name] and [Course] be retrieve from other sqlite database table and place inside the Microsoft word document automatically?

Is it possible or is there any other way to implement more feasible?  (Sorry I'm tried browsing the web but no relevant results)

Comment: Your question is not really comprehensible. Care to try again?

Comment: Hi, hope my edited explanation would be better to understand.

Comment: No, not really. I wish you luck regardless.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an open-source library that gives VBA code access to a SQLite database: http://sqliteforexcel.codeplex.com/.

I haven't tried it personally, but it looks pretty promising. What you would do, is write some simple VBA into you Word/Excel document (take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff604039.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814737.aspx) for help with that), and follow the steps on the above link to begin using the library. The download also comes with an example.

Comment: @user976050 This will only work with VBA. PHP doesn't need a special library as far as I know, since SQLite is built into PHP. Take a look at this tutorial for doing that: http://zetcode.com/databases/sqlitephptutorial/.